# Do Self Hosted Agents require dedicated machines?

Tags: azure-devops

I am migrating XAML Builds to Azure Devops. Goal is to remove the dedicated Build Staging server to cut costs.

Following is the process:
1) Build ASP.NET Web Application. 
2) Copy configs, assemblies, WebPackage from Build output to various folders in UNC share which will be later picked up by a Release Pipeline Job.

Since Microsoft Hosted Agents dont allow usage of UNC share, I wanted to use Self Hosted Agent.

Question:
Can I use a Self Hosted Agent without the necessity of a dedicated server to hold the Build Output in Image or Container which can then be copied to the UNC Share? I am new to Devops and hence the articles on MS confused me if I need a dedicated server or not.

Tried to set up a Self Hosted Agent pool, but the steps suggest that I require a machine where the Self Hosted Agent need to be setup. If this is the case then it means I will be requiring a dedicated machine like in XAML process. Am I blabbering? Please excuse if yes :-)

Expected Result: Run a Build Pipeline with Self Hosted Agents on Cloud without the requirement of a Dedicated Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNC Shares or not, the "self hosted agent" is an agent you install on your own server, there can be multiple reasons for that, for example accessing an sql server for testing that is on your own local network, to perform tests against during builds.

If you are trying to reduce costs, a self-hosted agent can be benefitial if you already have server hardware it can run on. If not, you might aswell just use a hosted build agent, anything build on that can be published directly azure devops or other places though various build tasks.

Comment: Oh so its mandatory that we have a dedicated server in case we use Self Hosted agents. That means we would have to retain the existing server so that we can copy the contents to that.  Your next suggestion. In case I use a Hosted Agent, can the build artifacts be directly handed over to the existing Release Pipeline (which is already in Azure devops) ? Then we can do away with the requirement of having an intermediate server just to hold it. Could u give me a brief hint into this?

Comment: @RamDin You can put build output into the: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` then use the task `Publish Build Artifact` to upload it to az devops, then other pipelines can use that build artifact. alternatively find another to move artifacts around, there are several other tasks you can use in az devops

Comment: Alternatively you can just install a deployment agent on your target server, then create a release pipeline that uses your build artifact and deploys that locally in the correct folder.

Comment: Thanks @Jim. Even though not exact, your answer gave me few hints on how to visualize the process from a top view. This just confirms my understanding of how to play around with "Build -> Deploy" handover. Just a limitation though. We are not supposed to touch the release pipeline because the agent used is On-Prem since it has to be shared by various intranet apps in the org.

Comment: Which one is better to have release agent on target machine? or to have centralized release machine that deploy to all target servers?

Answer (score 0):

> ...Since Microsoft Hosted Agents dont allow usage of UNC share...

This is not a problem, there is no reason for you to use UNC shares.

You don't need to access UNC shares to store artifacts for later consumption; use the Publish Artifacts build activity. That will store your build outputs internally and make them available to downstream releases.

Comment: The limitation for us is that we have to copy the Build output to a UNC Share eg: \\fx101\App\Version1.0\Release. Only then the downstream Release Pipeline can read the Build artifacts from here for deployment. Currently we have a dedicated build server with VSTS Build agent which does this. Since we are looking to move away from the dedicated server, we want to try this.